# How can I assign row numbers to the table I query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

It seems so simple, yet I was not able to find any solution that works for me.
My query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT bedType FROM room;
```

And the result shows:

```
  bedType
  King Bed
  Queen Bed
```

And I'm trying to assign just numerical value such as:

```
  bedType
1 King Bed
2 Queen Bed
```

I tried using `row_number()` but it didn't work. Is there a simple way of doing this?
Thank you in advance!

++

```
SELECT DISTINCT bedType, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bedType) FROM room;
```

This results in:

```
bedType ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bedType)
King Bed    1
King Bed    2
King Bed    3
King Bed    4
King Bed    5 
... 
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` as:

```
select row_number() over (order by bedtype), bedtype
from room
group by bedtype
```